# Execute command as you drink a water bottle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to execute a command as I drink a water bottle. I have made a scoreboard already.

```
scoreboard objectives add drinkPotion minecraft.used:minecraft.potion
```

But, the execute command that I used doesn't work because as I drink the potion, it turns into a glass bottle. (Water bottle is considered as a potion)

```
execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:potion",tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}},scores={drinkPotion=1..}] run command
```

Do any of you have a solution for this?

Comment: Why would you check for the item at all? Just use the scoreboard and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a tag that tells you if a player was recently holding a water bottle. These commands work for me, I put the first one into a repeating command block and the rest into chain command blocks:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:potion",tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}}] run tag @s add holdsWater
/execute as @a[nbt=!{SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:potion",tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}},scores={drinkPotion=0}] run tag @s remove holdsWater
/execute as @a[tag=holdsWater,scores={drinkPotion=1..}] run <command>
/scoreboard players reset * drinkPotion
```

The first command tags any player who is holding a water bottle
The second command removes the tag from any player who is not holding a water bottle, unless they just used a potion
The third command executes a command as any player who was just drinking a potion and has the `holdsWater` tag
The last command resets the scoreboard objective `drinkPotion`

Comment: Well, that was a stupid question to ask that I deleted it. I actually didn't test it out yet when I commented. I just assumed it works without it.

Comment: Well, you get the same problem as you had before when you remove the scores tag in the second command, it`s good that you ask if things are unclear though.